# how to translate method call into lambda expression

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I have a question about LinqToSql approach.

**Model:**

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Phone Phone { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public bool IsUkr()
    {
        return this.Number.StartsWith("380");
    }
}
```

I use Nhibernate as ORM and I want to execute

```
IQueryable<Phone> phones = session.Query<Phone>().Where(x => x.IsUkr());
```

But Nhibernate can't translate this expression into sql because it doesn't know about method IsUkr().

Solution is to write some wrapper to IQueryable interface and use:

```
session.Query<Phone>().ToExpandable().Where ....
```

But I don't understand how translate LambdaExpression **x => x.IsUkr()**       into
      **x => x.Number.StartsWith("380")**

Can someone help me?

Comment: If this is a routine check you may consider making this a computed property in the database table.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for idea. But there are many conditions like this to other properties in model, so this approach is not very good

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for, but you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26922208/1486443

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13679572/5126411

`IsUkr` criteria is specific for the `Phone` entity so you can just add a static method like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<Phone, bool>> IsUkr = x => x.Number.StartsWith("380");
```

and use it:

```
IQueryable<Phone> phones = session.Query<Phone>().Where(Phone.IsUkr);
```

Maybe it would be better to create a special static class for such methods/properties.

Comment: It's good idea and it works. But I want to know is it possible to create such expression at runtime